# Bash way to remove spaces in one column of huge file

Tags: macos, bash, file, spaces

I have a large (15 Gb) tab-delimered text file (say, 'Test.csv'):

```
ID1         ID2         ID3                  ID4
Some text   Some text   Text to be cleared   Some text
```

The problem is how to remove all spaces in column ID3 by means of bash script (Mac OS X 10.10). Thus, the result should be as follows:

```
ID1         ID2         ID3                  ID4
Some text   Some text   Texttobecleared   Some text
```

Column delimeter is '\t'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{gsub(" ", "", $3); print}' < file
```

Replace `file` with the path to your file.

The `-F"\t"` says to use a tab character as a separator when identifying columns from the input.

The `-v OFS="\t"` says to use a tab character to separate columns in the output.

The `gsub` modifies column 3 `$3` and replaces all spaces `" "` with an empty string.

Comment: You need to add `-v OFS="\t"` to avoid changing the output separators to spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you, guys! Unfortunately, only one answer could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With bash's builtin commands:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read id1 id2 id3 id4; do echo -e "$id1\t$id2\t${id3// /}\t$id4"; done < file_original > file_new
```

Output:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4
Some text       Some text       Texttobecleared Some text
```

Comment: You should probably be using `read -r` to avoid messing up the content.  Points for trying, but experience suggests that using Bash built-ins like this is actually going to be slower than a simple tool like Awk.

Answer (score 1):

Sed way

```
sed ':T;s/^\(\([^\t]*\t\)\{2\}\)\([^\t]*\) /\1\3/;tT' file
```

or with GNU and -r

```
ssed -r ':T;s/^(([^\t]*\t){2})([^\t]*) /\1\3/;tT' file
```